# Best way or practice to traverse multiple databases in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a restaurant booking website. Each restaurant has its own database. *ex: r1 has dr1 DB, r2 has dr2 DB, etc...*

Bookings can be made through either parent site(*my booking site*) or various classified sites(*third party sites*). *ex: r1 and r2 are referred by classified site(cl_site1)*.

```
DB: dr1
Table: booking
id customer time  date       ref_by 
-----------------------------------
1  xxx      19:30 31/05/2015 cl_site1
2  yyy      20:00 05/06/2015 cl_site2
3  zzz      21:00 04/06/2015 parent
...

DB: dr2
Table: booking
id customer time  date       ref_by 
------------------------------------
1  aaa      19:30 02/06/2015 cl_site1
2  ccc      20:00 03/06/2015 cl_site3
3  bbb      21:00 07/06/2015 parent
...
```

Like wise I have 100s of restaurants and 1000s of bookings.

Now I want to build a new site where these classified sites(*site1, site2, etc...*) can fetch their corresponding bookings of the restaurants referred by them(*site1 can fetch r1 and r2 bookings referred by site1*).

I think it's not a good practice if I fetch the data by traverse each and every database in run time.

Let me know what way I should follow in mysql to do this in an efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you have many options with the current setup. You can create a central table for the references and maintain it using triggers. Or better, merge all the bookings to one table.

Comment: You'd probably be better using a single database, and having a restaurant id on all relevant tables

Comment: Apart from booking I am doing lot of other stuffs. Each database has more than 150 tables so single database would not be the best solution. Can I use views???

Comment: Using a single database would make things a lot easier: you asked about best practise, best practise is to use a single database as much as possibe